# I am stuck in the middle, webpart is not displayed. It shows stack overflow exception

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am stuck in the middle, webpart is not displayed. It shows stack overflow exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Shraepoint 2010 data form webpart wont display more than 70 fields.
may be because of this you are getting stack overflow exception.
if you have requirement to display more than 70 fields it is better to divide into two data form webparts.

for more information visit this blog http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/11a8b7c7-6bdd-485e-a8c6-083896cf6f83